# MySQL join with Direct table or subfields of table

Tags: mysql, performance, join

First query:

```
SELECT  
    u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,
    u.tazkera_id,
    cu.relation_type,
    CASE csp.`shift`
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Morning'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Afternoon'
        else 'Neither'
    END AS shift
FROM `course_user` as cu
LEFT JOIN `courses` as c ON c.id = cu.`course_id`
LEFT JOIN (
    select users.id,
           users.first_name,
           users.last_name,
           users.tazkera_id
           FROM `users`
) as u ON u.id = cu.`user_id`

left JOIN `course_schedule_prefs`   as csp ON csp.`user_id` = cu.`user_id`

Where cu.relation_type = 1 group by cu.`user_id`;
```

Second Query:

```
SELECT  
    u.id,
    u.first_name,
    u.last_name,
    u.tazkera_id,
    cu.relation_type,
    CASE csp.`shift`
        WHEN '1' THEN 'Morning'
        WHEN '2' THEN 'Afternoon'
        else 'Neither'
    END AS shift
FROM `course_user` as cu
LEFT JOIN `courses` as c ON c.id = cu.`course_id`
LEFT JOIN users as u ON u.id = cu.`user_id`
left JOIN `course_schedule_prefs`   as csp ON csp.`user_id` = cu.`user_id`
Where cu.relation_type = 1 group by cu.`user_id`;
```

Tables :

users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_password_reset` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_ip` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_email_address_verified` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `failed_login_attempts` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_failed_login_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `tazkera_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `province_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `village` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `home_address` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `promote_unique_user_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `forgot_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email_confirm_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `district_other` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `father_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `training_provider_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_profile_completed` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `picture` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `small_picture` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_poll` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_password_reset` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `presence_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auto_presence` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_activity` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `trash` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `login_approval` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lang` varchar(2) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'en',
  `cover` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `small_cover` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `forum_reputation` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_suspension_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `forum_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `users_email_unique` (`email`),
  KEY `users_training_provider_id_foreign` (`training_provider_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_training_provider_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`training_provider_id`) REFERENCES `training_providers` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1000038 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

course_users:

```
CREATE TABLE `course_user` (
  `course_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `relation_type` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  KEY `course_user_course_id_foreign` (`course_id`),
  KEY `course_user_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `course_user_course_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`course_id`) REFERENCES `courses` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `course_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

courses;

```
CREATE TABLE `courses` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `curriculum_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `training_center_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `training_coordinator_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `focal_point_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `shift` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `stream_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `master_trainer_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pre_test_generated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_test_generated` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `conduct_days` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `evaluation_available` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `courses_curriculum_id_foreign` (`curriculum_id`),
  KEY `courses_training_coordinator_id_foreign` (`training_coordinator_id`),
  KEY `courses_focal_point_id_foreign` (`focal_point_id`),
  KEY `courses_stage_id_foreign` (`stage_id`),
  KEY `courses_stream_id_foreign` (`stream_id`),
  KEY `courses_unit_id_foreign` (`unit_id`),
  KEY `courses_master_trainer_id_foreign` (`master_trainer_id`),
  KEY `courses_training_center_id_foreign` (`training_center_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `courses_curriculum_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`curriculum_id`) REFERENCES `curriculums` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_focal_point_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`focal_point_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_master_trainer_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`master_trainer_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_stage_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`stage_id`) REFERENCES `stages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_stream_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`stream_id`) REFERENCES `streams` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_training_center_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`training_center_id`) REFERENCES `training_centers` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `courses_training_coordinator_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`training_coordinator_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `courses_unit_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`unit_id`) REFERENCES `units` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=139 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

course_schedule_prefs;

```
CREATE TABLE `course_schedule_prefs` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cunduct_days` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `training_centers` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `shift` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `course_schedule_prefs_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `course_schedule_prefs_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

My question is , which one of this query is good in term of performance and accuracy. Why ?

first query: I join directly with table; select all columns of table.

Second query: I used subquery inside of join; select only those element which I need it.

Note : My main question is about `users` table which is in join

Comment: As long as accuracy is concern it can't be commented unless you provide some sample and expected data out of sample. And for performance it again there are many factors which are accountable for making a query good or bad. In general the 2nd approach is better but again you need to check the query health using `explain` and see how mysql optimizer does to the query.

Comment: If the query is semantically identical (as far as I can tell it is) there should be no relevant difference (optimization may take different amounts of time). MySQL should be smart enough to only move those values around it may actually use at some point. And why don't you try? At least performance can be tested (beware caching!). Oh btw: if you don't use indexes, my answer may be false ...

Comment: Do you need `LEFT`?  If not, remove it from the question.  I say this because the 'correct' answer will be different.

Comment: What percentage of `cu` rows have `relation_type = 1`?  I ask that because it smells like a flag.  Indexes on flags tend to be ignored.  And that makes a difference in how these queries will be performed.

Comment: @jakumi , I am not using indexes.

Comment: @RickJames, 80% of it.

Comment: No indexes?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

Comment: @NimatullahRazmjo you really should use indexes ... and read up on them ;o)

Comment: @RickJames, I update the question. Please check it out

Comment: I added to my answer.

Comment: @RickJames, I added two more table. About indexing, I dont have that privilege to add indexes for that table. My jobs is to write a query for table. I have talked with owner, but he said kept the way it is :). anyway thanks for `many:many` relation.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many possibilities here.  There is no simple, 'straight', answer.

With `LEFT JOIN` (instead of `JOIN`), the Optimizer cannot start with the subquery, which it would *usually* like to do.

If there is a `WHERE` clause *and* it is useful for filtering rows, the Optimizer would like to start with the table that is filtered the most.  Your `WHERE` clause smells like a flag, which is usually not very useful.

If a subquery has a `GROUP BY` or `LIMIT`, then it may significantly shrink the number of rows to work with.  (Not in your case.)  This *might* make the subquery approach better.

If `cu` has `INDEX(relation_type, user_id)`, the Optimizer *may* decide that handling all of the `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` leads to the best bet, thereby starting with `cu` as the 'first' table.

In *old* versions of MySQL, subqueries in `JOIN ( SELECT ... )` had no way of getting an index, thereby leading to inefficient table scans of that tmp table.  In *new* versions (starting with 5.6, I think), the Optimizer takes the extra step (which costs something) to generate the optimal index (`(id)` in this case) after creating the tmp table and before `JOINing` it.

**More**

- 2 more table definitions needed.
- Do you have the indexes I suggested?
- InnoDB really needs a `PRIMARY KEY` - See [*many:many*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) for advice on `course_user`.